# "Enable Clickonce Security Settings" keeps enabling itself

Tags: winforms, security, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I uncheck "Enable Clickonce Security Settings" and then publish... and it re-enables.

Why does it re-enable and what can be done to stop it from re-enabling itself?

I've been able to publish this application - and others - with clickonce disabled... but now, all of a sudden, it won't let me publish without re-enabling the checkbox.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm actually running into this exact issue now.