# ClickOnce Security Settings Re-enables Itself When Publishing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I'm observing very strange behavior with ClickOnce. In Visual Studio (2015), under the "Security" tab, there is an option labeled `Enable ClickOnce security settings`. I need to disable this so I can include `Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls, Version 6.0.0.0` in my application (to provides ToolTips for the instance of the CefSharp browser that I'm using). Having it enabled throws an error when the aforementioned Win32 package is included. Unfortunately, any time I hit Publish, Visual Studio automatically re-enables this setting (throwing the error again).

*Note: this is the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493629/enable-clickonce-security-settings-keeps-enabling-itself) by another poster, but no one ever answered it.*