# "ClickOnce does not support" visual studio Bug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to publish my C# app, but I got the error `"ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'”`.

Then I tried to uncheck "Enable ClickOnce security settings" [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11036922/9114020).

but when I click "Publish" the "Enable Clickonce Security Settings" re-enables, like [this un answerd question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40493629/9114020)

Therefore I can't cancel the error `"ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'”`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023998/clickonce-does-not-support-the-request-execution-level-requireadministrator)

Comment: The answer, by Brian (and duplicated below) in that original question was the same thing you could have tried here.  (See `asInvoker` notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an 'app.manifest' that sets this. Open it make sure it contains:

```
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the application properties (right-click on the solution file and click the properties), then go the security tab.
Then disable the *click-once* security setting check box.
That will work.